# EHCache JMS Replication Limit Number of Threads?

Tags: java, jms, ehcache

Essentially this part of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566264/ehcache-hibernate-and-rmi-replication-with-large-number-of-entities):

> -> It seems ehcache/ hibernate creates 1 cache per Entity. This is fine, however when replication is in place it create 1 thread / cache
>   to replicate. Is this the intended behavious ? As our domain is big,
>   it creates about 300 threads, which seems to me really big

Is there no option to pool or consolidate the number of replication threads?

Answer (score 1):

The code around replication has not changed in a number of years, so the limitation is still there. As described in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/897026/18591) to the linked question you will have to code what you need yourself.

Now Ehcache considers replication to be deprecated and favours Terracotta clustering in order to provide some consistency guarantees. Details of that are beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Hm, deprecated, don't like the sound of that. Do you have any info on what replacing ehcache-jms with Terracotta might look like?